# Downloading a Maven dependency from Artifactory results in two JAR and POM files being downloaded

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a Maven SNAPSHOT artifact in Artifactory with version 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT. Its JAR and POM file has a date suffix appended to it, which was created automatically when the artifact was uploaded. If another version of the dependency is uploaded the previous one is replaced.

When I use Maven to fetch the dependency, two sets of JAR and POM files are downloaded into my .m2 folder: one set that has the date suffix, and one without. They are identical apart from the name. For example:

```
my-great-app.v1_0-1.2.4-20240308.075827-2.jar
my-great-app.v1_0-1.2.4-20240308.075827-2.pom
my-great-app.v1_0-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
my-great-app.v1_0-1.2.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

This happens for multiple artifacts that I have in Artifactory. I make sure to clean the .m2 folder before downloading them.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can this cause any issues?
3. Can or should I fix this, if so: how?

Comment: This is how maven handles metadata in SNAPSHOTs internally.  You can look at the source code to learn more.